# Access switch management on network without dhcp

Tags: ip, dhcp, switch

Could not find default IP of cisco router which was static. Issue is now solved see answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You mention a Cisco switch.. Why not use the awesome console cable for it to login and set an IP on it?</strike>

Searching a bit, and it looks like the switch got a default IP in the 192.168.1.0 network - more precisely, it seems to have 192.168.1.254

Try setting a static IP and access that IP.

Comment: It doesn't have one :( It's a Cisco SG200-50P (small business)

Comment: @PieterLewyllie answer updated

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of the switch?
Does it have a serial connection? In that case you can configure the IP on the switch.